# Search through FullCalendar

Tags: php, mysql, fullcalendar, timetable

I am building a college timetable with FullCalendar, php and mysql. 
Events are created when you click in the calendar field; you assign a name for the event, a professor and a room. The event is saved in an sql databse. 
I would like to add a search bar which would search through the timetable; a user could search for either professor, room number, event name. The timetable would update as the user types and it would re-fetch the event with that room number/event name/professor name.

Anyone have any clue how to do this?

This is the code i am using for rendering events from the mysql:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, title, naem, mentor, start, end, color FROM events ";
$req = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$req->execute();
$events = $req->fetchAll();
...  
...
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        height:595,
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        minTime: "07:00:00",
        maxTime: "16:00:00",
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, 
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        firstDay:"1",
        select: function(start, end) {
            $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
            $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
            $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
        },
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            element.bind('dblclick', function() {
                $('#ModalEdit #id').val(event.id);
                $('#ModalEdit #title').val(event.title);
                $('#ModalEdit #naem').val(event.naem);
                $('#ModalEdit #mentor').val(event.mentor);
                $('#ModalEdit #color').val(event.color);
                $('#ModalEdit').modal('show');
            });
                element.find('.fc-title').append("<br/>" + event.naem + "<br/>" + event.mentor); 

        },
        eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) { 

            edit(event);

        },
        eventResize: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,revertFunc) {

            edit(event);

        },
        events: [
        <?php foreach($events as $event): 

            $start = explode(" ", $event['start']);
            $end = explode(" ", $event['end']);
            if($start[1] == '00:00:00'){
                $start = $start[0];
            }else{
                $start = $event['start'];
            }
            if($end[1] == '00:00:00'){
                $end = $end[0];
            }else{
                $end = $event['end'];
            }
        ?>
            {
                id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
                title: '<?php echo $event['title']; ?>',
                naem: '<?php echo $event['naem']; ?>',
                mentor: '<?php echo $event['mentor']; ?>',
                start: '<?php echo $start; ?>',
                end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
                color: '<?php echo $event['color']; ?>',
            },
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        ]
    });

    function edit(event){
        start = event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
        if(event.end){
            end = event.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
        }else{
            end = start;
        }

        id =  event.id;

        Event = [];
        Event[0] = id;
        Event[1] = start;
        Event[2] = end;

        $.ajax({
         url: 'editEventDate.php',
         type: "POST",
         data: {Event:Event},
         success: function(rep) {
                if(rep == 'OK'){
                    alert('Spremljeno!');
                }else{
                    alert('Nešto zajebaje...'); 
                }
            }
        });
    }

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

An autocomplete plugin such as this will help with the UI part: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Using this your user can find the IDs of the people / rooms / event names involved and choose one from the list of possibilities. You will need an ajax call and an associated server endpoint which will search the database based on what the user types into the box and return any matching results.

Then in fullCalendar use this format for your event feed https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/ so that you can pass the selected ID from the autocomplete to the server as an extra parameter when fetching events.

Next listen to the autocomplete's "select" event (http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) and when a value is chosen, call "refetchEvents" (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/refetchEvents/) on the fullCalendar. This will update your events list, restricting it by the specific person/room/event ID as well as the standard parameters (i.e. those being the current start/end dates of the visible view).

Comment: i have no idea how to do this :(
would you be so kind to show me?

Comment: which part(s) of the suggestion don't you understand? If you treat each thing I mentioned as a separate task, they are all documented through those links and on their own are relatively simple. Have you read those documents and not understood something? It would help if you are specific about the issue you're facing

Comment: i'm new to php and jquery. if the code for this is not too long, would you consider typing it down for me? i can provide you with the rest of the code i have so far if you would need it...

Comment: yes, please edit the question with the relevant parts of your existing code. There's quite a bit to do, I will do my best to give you the key parts of the solution when I have a bit of time.

Comment: would it be more convenient if i gave you the entire page code? maybe my email?

Comment: not really, I doubt I need all of it. The complete fullCalendar config is useful, and also some details of your database. Do you have tables which list the possible professors and rooms? Or is it just typed into your events table as free text directly, with no lookups?

Comment: i made a separate page, where i create professors and upload them and their information to a database. didn't do this for the rooms but i planed to. Later, i would list the professors and the rooms in a currently existing modal which opens when assigning an event to a timetable slot.

Comment: any progress so far?